# Ordering invoice numbers and letters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm having problems with SQL sorting results of a query from my MySQL database. I need a way to sort invoice numbers mixed with letters and a multi digit number.

Format is: ${optional-prefix}${number part}${optional-postfix} and they are all stored in Varchar(32). It is not an option to change the number format, because the values are imported from multiple systems.

What i want to sort: (unsorted)

- IoCustTextNoNumber
- Io-700
- IO39ABC
- IO-137-kk
- IO-037-kk
- 201-ib
- 201
- 38-kk
- 036
- 12
- 11-KE
- IO-37-kk
- 00001342
- IO-36-kk
- 11-KEk
- 13
- 035
- 37-kk
- 200
- Io-701

Expected result: (sorted)

- 11-KE
- 11-KEk
- 12
- 13
- 035
- 036
- 37-kk
- 38-kk
- 200
- 201
- 201-ib
- 00001342
- IO-36-kk
- IO-037-kk
- IO-37-kk
- IO-137-kk
- Io-700
- Io-701
- IO39ABC
- IoCustTextNoNumber

Can anyone help me with a solution?

Comment: Honestly, the "sorted" example makes no sense. 1 comes before 0, 3 comes before 2, then multiple zeroes come before number 2 etc. - create a column in your db that represents order_id and sort them manually, I can't see any type of algorithm here that follows any sort of logic.

Comment: No, the sorting is ok. This is because 036 is treated as 36 and therefore comes before 37. In my sorted case 036 should be after 11, because 036 = 36

Comment: Your "sorting" system isn't following any rules. 036 can't be 36 because it's not, at least not to MySQL. You **have** to build custom ordering here, there's no way to do this via MySQL.

Comment: We see the leading 0 as part of the number, and when sorting the number part naturally, the 036 should be treated as 36. But this is a tiny detail in the overall sorting problem, and either way of sorting 036 would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is not going to do that. You can build a custom sort in something like PHP and you do a for loop and assign things to a position. Or, You can select all that begin with lo and then update all of those to put lo into another column.

In php you could do something like:

```
foreach($data => row){

   $test = strpos('-', $row); // If this is successful than it has a dash in the string, and it goes towards the front.

  if(!$test) { // If its not a test does it begin with a number.
     if($row[0] >= 0){
         // Do whatever you need
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: I've tried this method

ORDER BY
 column + 0 <> 0 DESC,
 column + 0,
 column

This method almost works, but not with the middle number part.

Comment: Mysql is not designed to do this.  You need an entirely customly sorted system.  You have to build it programatically.